# Angular 2 component testing with Jasmine spies "No provider for Http!" error

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, components

I am trying to test an Angular 2 component that uses a service. The service has Http injected into it, which I am not interested in testing so I am trying to mock the service and spy on the service's method call. This is something I was quite familiar with doing in Angular 1 but I just can't get to work in Angular 2. The error I'm getting is No provider for Http! I am interested in spying on the actual services method rather than mocking it out.

My component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavBarLink } from '../../models/nav-bar-link';
import { NavBarService } from '../../services/nav-bar/nav-bar.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-bar',
    providers: [NavBarService],
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'nav-bar.template.html'
})
export class NavBarComponent {
  constructor(private _navBarService: NavBarService) { }

 links: NavBarLink[];

 getLinks(): void {
  this._navBarService.getNavBarLinks().then(data => this.links = data);
 }

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getLinks();
  }
}
```

And my service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Urls } from '../../constants/urls.constants';
import { NavBarLink } from '../../models/nav-bar-link';

@Injectable()
export class NavBarService {
    constructor(private _http: Http,
                private _urls: Urls) { }

    getNavBarLinks():Promise<NavBarLink[]> {

        return this._http.get(this._urls.NAV_BAR_LINKS)    
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                 let navLinks = [];
                 for(let navLink of response.json()) {
                    navLinks.push(new NavBarLink(navLink.id,        navLink.description, navLink.route));
                }
                return navLinks;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

}
```

And finally my test looks like this

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';

import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar.component';
import { NavBarService } from '../../services/nav-bar/nav-bar.service';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

let comp: NavBarComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavBarComponent>;
let navBarService;

class MockNavBarService extends NavBarService{
    constructor() {
        super(null, null);
     }
}

describe ('NavBarComponent tests', () => {

    beforeEach( async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [ NavBarComponent ],
                providers: [ {provide: NavBarService, useClass:     MockNavBarService} ]
            })
            .compileComponents()
            .then(createComponent);
    }));


    it('should call the getNavBarLinks when ngOnInit is called', () => {
        comp.ngOnInit();
        expect(navBarService.getNavBarLinks).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});

function createComponent() {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavBarComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    navBarService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NavBarService);

    spyOn(navBarService,    'getNavBarLinks').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve([]));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for your help everyone, it got me looking in the right area. What was missing was importing HttpModule. Big thanks to the Ahmed for suggesting this. Here is my fixed test for reference:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; // <==== IMPORT THIS

import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar.component';
import { NavBarService } from '../../services/nav-bar/nav-bar.service';
import { Urls } from '../../constants/urls.constants';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

let comp: NavBarComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavBarComponent>;
var navBarService;

describe ('NavBarComponent tests', () => {

    beforeEach( async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [ NavBarComponent ],
                imports: [ HttpModule], //<==IMPORT INTO TEST BED
                providers: [
                    Urls,
                    MockBackend,
                    NavBarService ]
            })
           .compileComponents()
           .then(createComponent);
    }));


    it('should call the getNavBarLinks when ngOnInit is called', () => {
        comp.ngOnInit();
        expect(navBarService.getNavBarLinks).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});

function createComponent() {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavBarComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    navBarService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NavBarService);

    spyOn(navBarService,     'getNavBarLinks').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve([]));
}
```

No need for mock objects or anything, perfect

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you're bringing in modules that are dependencies of services that your component consumes which adds complexity to your component test. Any time NavBarService changes its providers you have to update every test file that consumes or relies on the NavBarComponent. By mocking the service with a class that does not extend the original service you cut that dependency complexity off at its root. This will make your tests cleaner and less susceptible to needing attention if you change the service.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this

```
@Component({
    providers: [NavBarService],   <==== !!!!!
})
export class NavBarComponent {
```

The `@Component.providers` takes precendence over anything provided and the module level. So Angular will try to create the instance of the `NavBarService` instead of using the mock you configured in the test.

Angular allows us to override the `@Component.providers`, as well as other things like the `@Component.template`. We can do that with the following

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [NavBarComponent]
})
.overrideComponent(NavBarComponent, {
  set: {
    providers: [
      { provide: NavBarService, useClass: MockNavBarService}
    ]
  }
})
.compileComponents()
 .then(createComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that MockNavBarService extends NavBarService, so Http is still expected to be provided. I don't understand the technical reason why this is the case, but there it is. If you remove the inheritance you could instead implement a mock `getNavBarLinks()` which returns an Observable of some canned data. Then in your test you could test what NavBarComponent does with the data rather than test the fact that some method got called.